# Passing Dynamic Arguments to foreach command

Tags: function, arguments, tcl

I want to pass the argument (var list) dynamically to the `foreach` command.
I tried this:

```
% set names {Alice Bob Charlie}
Alice Bob Charlie
% foreach name $names {puts $name}
Alice
Bob
Charlie
% set foreachArg {name $names}
name $names
% foreach $foreachArg {puts $name}
wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command"
% foreach {*}$foreachArg {puts $name}
$names
% foreach {*}[set foreachArg] {puts $name}
$names
% foreach {*}[list [set foreachArg]] {puts $name}
wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command"
```

Here I want to pass the `name $names` part as a dynamic argument. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the root of the problem is that you are using a literal string `$names` instead of the variable `$names` in the `$foreachArg` variable to do this. It might be easier if you do:

```
set foreachArg "name $names"
```

But that would result in the `$foreachArg` to contain the plain list `name Alice Bob Charlie`.

So this would be better:

```
set foreachArg "name [list $names]"
foreach {*}$foreachArg {puts $name}
```

---

If you still want to use braces, it's a little more complex in that would probably need to use [`subst`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm) to first 'convert' the literal `$foreachArg` by the variable `$foreachArg` but you could still need to bring the list one level deeper in the list:

```
set foreachArg {name [list $names]}
foreach {*}[subst $foreachArg] {puts $name}
```

Comment: So, when your list is not yet there (but could possibly raed later from file), then it is necesary to use the bracs approach, right?

Comment: I'd go with: `set foreachArg [list name $names]`…